# Factory function template that creates objects from a class template?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two factory function templates `makeObjectA` and `makeObjectB` which create instances from a class template (`ClassTemplateA` and `ClassTemplateB`). The `makeObject` functions call another function template (`create`) which actually instantiates objects and performs some generic initialization. The `create` function template thus needs two template parameters, one that specifies what type of object to create, and another that is passed as the object's template argument.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do, but I don't understand why this code won't compile, and how to fix it?

`factory.h(17): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition`

**ClassTemplates.h**

```
#pragma once

template <typename T>
class ClassTemplateA {

public:
    ClassTemplateA() {}

};

template <typename T>
class ClassTemplateB {

public:
    ClassTemplateB() {}

};
```

**Factory.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "ClassTemplates.h"

template <typename T>
ClassTemplateA<T>& makeObjectA()
{
    return create<ClassTemplateA, T>();
}

template <typename T>
ClassTemplateB<T>& makeObjectB()
{
    return create<ClassTemplateB, T>();
}

template<typename TClassTemplate, typename T>
TClassTemplate<T>& create()
{
    TClassTemplate<T>* object = new TClassTemplate<T>();

    // Do some generic initialization after construction.

    return *object;
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "ClassTemplates.h"
#include "Factory.h"

int main() 
{
    ClassTemplateA<int>& objectA = makeObjectA<int>();
    ClassTemplateB<int>& objectB = makeObjectB<int>();
}
```

Comment: Why the `static`?

Comment: I don't think C++ cares about `TClassTemplate<T>` as the return type... so I don't think you need to (or can) template the template in the `create()`.

Comment: I suggest to return smart pointer or value instead of reference BTW. your interface can easily be misused and creates memory leak.

Comment: I was aware of memory leak, just wanted to create the simplest example that demostrates the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want template template argument:

```
template <template <typename> class TClassTemplate, typename T>
TClassTemplate<T>& create()
{
    TClassTemplate<T>* object = new TClassTemplate<T>();

    // Do some generic initialization after construction.

    return *object;
};
```